# TinyMce 6 - prevent past image

Tags: image, tinymce, copy-paste, tinymce-6

I'm currently using tinymce and I want to prevent that some user can copy/past an image inside the text.

Currently the only doc I see is about powerpast, an idea if it's possible to prevent this kind of behaviour ?

Thanks.

I actually try to "force plain text" with "oninit:'setPlainText'", but it change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is not possible at the moment in TinyMCE 6

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/7809

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, finally I deal it like this :

```
init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    editor.on('Paste', function (e) {
        var items = (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
        for (index in items) {
            var item = items[index];
            if(item.kind === 'file'){
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        }
    });
}
```